# Windows Server 2008 R2 Upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

Does anyone know how to upgrade or has upgraded a PowerEdge R510 Server from Windows Server 2008 R2 to at least Windows Server 2012 OS? I need to get this server's OS upgraded.

Comment: In most cases you don't, so many things could go wrong so you install a new machine, and then migrate services, and finally decommission the old one.

Comment: We'd most definitely would rather migrate to 2016 but from research, it seems that this server only goes up to 2012. I've heard that many things can go wrong when updating a physical server and also seems like a lot of work if you even know what you're doing. Also, I was told a way to upgrade the OS would be to wipe the server clean and do a fresh install. Does that seem feasible at all or have you ever done it this way?

Comment: [See Official Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/upgrade/upgrade-2008r2-to-2012r2) about howto do it

Comment: See also Question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/791521/upgrade-windows-server-2008-r2-standard-to-server-2012-r2-standard?rq=1)   [here2](https://serverfault.com/questions/980761/silent-in-place-upgrade-server-2008-r2-to-server-2012-r2?rq=1)  
or    [here3](https://serverfault.com/questions/984743/in-place-upgrade-of-vm-running-2008-r2?rq=1)   or [here4](https://serverfault.com/questions/447274/windows-server-2008-r2-upgrade-via-remote-desktop?rq=1)